# Country Restrictions - How does Facebook determine a user's location when filtering gated content?

Tags: facebook, location, facebook-page

How is a location determined when showing restricted posts from a page's wall?

Here is the configuration option I am talking about (on a page's settings page)

[image: Country Restrictions]

My scenario is: I have a sever based in the UK which is using the user's auth token to show posts which are gated. Obviously I would like US based users to see these posts.

Will it take into account

- My server's IP address?
- The location the user has specified on their profile?
- The IP the user used to sign up with? --- or something else?

To clarify I have set my location in my profile to be a place in the US, but don't see the posts (when calling the API, or when just viewing the page)
Also, when I log into my UK based account from the US, I still don't see the posts (from API, or from just viewing the page)

Oddly enough, when logged in from the US server, Facebook asks me to validate my account and suggests a UK based mobile number (+44) - could be related to the fact I signed up from the UK? 
I have no way of creating an account that is US based because I don't have a US based mobile I can verify with.

Comment: The difference you are saying, could you please clarify a little on it. Does it shows you the post even when you mention in your profile different location? Mostly the filtering is done by Facebook based on the User's current location.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some testing on this.

I'm in Spain but wanted to see a page I'd restricted to UK only.

- I set my current location and home town to London:  Did not work
- I verified my UK phone (roaming): Did not work
- Used a VPN service (hidemyass) to give me a UK IP: Did not work

With the account set like that, no other changes.  I called a mate and got him to login to the account in the UK and the page became visible.

So can assume that settings of the account do not affect, and that FB are detecting VPN based traffic - maybe from database list of datacentre IP addresses.

And that it uses a (non-datacentre) IP address detection to determine if you are in this country.  Also follows that if you travel abroad you won't be able to see content even if you do "live" in that country.  I'm guess if you 'like' the page, then travel you would still be able to see it.